# Why is my paragraph popup coming outside my div with the "mousedown" event?

Tags: html, css

I need to show my paragraph inside my `<div>` when click on the `<div>`. This is my code:

```js
const area = document.getElementById("area");
const popup = document.getElementById("popup");

function showPopup(event) {
    let x = event.clientX;
    let y = event.clientY;
    popup.style.left = `${x}px`;
    popup.style.top = `${y}px`;
    popup.style.visibility = "visible";
}

area.addEventListener("mousedown", showPopup);
```

```css
.area {
    border: 1px solid;
    position: absolute;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}

.popup {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="area" class="area">
    <p class="popup" id="popup">popup</p>
</div>
```

Note that this is inside another main body `<div>` (also with `position: absolute`).

Comment: Hi, absolute element always needs to placed within a div with position relative depending on your design otherwise, it will consider body tag as relative for it's positioning. From MDN - An absolutely positioned element is an element whose computed position value is absolute or fixed. The top, right, bottom, and left properties specify offsets from the edges of the element's containing block. (The containing block is the ancestor relative to which the element is positioned.)

Comment: .deel1 {
    margin: auto;
    width: 80%;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    padding: 8px;
    border: 1px dashed #d0d0d0;
    position: absolute;
    height: 1700px;
} 

this the class of my div who takes whole the body. you'r saying i only have to make the paragraph position absolute in this case?

Comment: clientX and clientY are ead-only property of the MouseEvent interface provides the **horizontal** and **vertical** coordinate within the application's client area at which the event occurred (as opposed to the coordinate within the page).

Comment: The question is I still don't know what are your exact requirements?
Do you want the top left corner of your  `<p>` element be positioned where the pointer of the mouse is when we click?

Comment: @EhsanT i want that the paragraph apears at the location where i click inside my div

Comment: Disappear or appear?

Comment: @EhsanT appear i'm sorry indeed :)

Comment: No worries. And one last question, do you care about the edge cases like for now you have a 200px x 200px div, what should happen if you click on the cordination 199px, 199px(bottom right corner of the div) ? Should be a mechanism to identify this edge case and show the `<p>` element inside the `<div>` or for case like this it's OK to show it outside?

Comment: @EhsanT no it doesn't matter actualy, by the way it works perfectly if i do it on an indipedent page , so i'm sure it has something to do with this div who overlapse whole the body (see second excercise) or maybe this div who is above #myConsole {
    height: 40em;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    border: 2px solid #c0c0c0;
    padding: 4px;
}

Comment: anyway it's just an excercise for school and apparently we don't lose the much points if we do it in an external page, so don't break your head about it. i would be just happy if it worked one day and understand why he doesn't take the X & Y of the parent div

Comment: Can you please check if this snippet is what you're looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/yp9amfz7/

Comment: @EhsanT that's exactly what i try to achieve, and on a seperate page it works perfectly , just not on my main page within a other div who overlapse the body , with another div who comes before i'm sure the problem is somewhere there. i'll share whole my code when i have time . already alot of thanks for helping me so far :)

Comment: It would be helpful if we have the whole code which you have to be able to identify the issue.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this

```
 <div id="area">
<div class="area""
        <p class="popup" id="popup">popup</p>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: still same problem :(

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and observed you are changing style.top property based on your ClientX value which is causing popup element to appear over random position. Use following updated code and it's should be good.

```
function showPopup(event) {
console.log(event.clientX, event.clientY)

    let x = event.clientX;
    let y = event.clientY;
    popup.style.left = `${x - 8}px`;
    popup.style.top = `${y - 8}px`;
    popup.style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

and few CSS changes as -

```
.area {
    border: 1px solid;
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}

.popup {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
}
```

For more close positioning of popup element.

Comment: Thanks for your effort but still doesn't work ☹️ Note that this is still in another div who overlap whole the body and their are still other divs in the body

Comment: but if i do it it works in an external page so i'm sure it had something to with the parent divs of this code (.deel1 { margin: auto; width: 80%; background-color: #f0f0f0; padding: 8px; border: 1px dashed #d0d0d0; position: absolute; height: 1700px; }) is the one who overlaps whole the body, and  #myConsole { height: 40em; background-color: black; color: white; border: 2px solid #c0c0c0; padding: 4px; } is the one above